# On The Next Bit Test

Tags: random-number-generator, probability

I would like to know what $O(v(n))$ really means in detailed and simple words please.
I found it everywhere in the literature I am reviewing but I cannot find what the intuition of it (especially if it means the Big O Notation, then what it has to do with the Probability here; also what is $v$, it is never defined except in another paper as a constant -but maybe not related directly to v in this formula-).

[image]

Many Thanks.

**References** [1](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/64a0/4803b398ba8fbb25cab7ebff2c584bb8a7db.pdf) , [2](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-38424-3_29.pdf)

Comment: can you give a reference to where you got the quote from and what [1] is? after all, others may be better than you in tracing references. took a quick look at two references, I did not see any $\nu(n)$.

Comment: @kodlu Just added the references. This (1) is the equation number whereas $s{_1}^{i-1}$  means the subsequence  starting  at the first bit and ends at $i-1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But this notation is defined (informally) in the first paper.

> The notation $O(\nu(n))$ is used for any
> function, $f(n)$, that vanishes faster than the inverse
> of any polynomial, that is for every polynomial, $\mathrm{poly}
> (n)$, and $n$ large enough, $f(n) \leq 1/\mathrm{poly}(n)$

Therefore, what it means is no probabilistic polynomial time (PPT) algorithm $A$ can guess the next bit at inverse polynomially decreasing error rate.

Given any PPT algorithm $A$ this error probability *decays* super-polynomially, for example at a rate $\exp(-\log^2 n)$ which goes to zero faster than any polynomial.

**Claim:** $\exp(-\log^2 n)$ is less than $n^{-c}$ for any constant $c$ for $n$ large enough.

*Proof:* Look at the reciprocal. $$\exp(\log^2 n) > n^c$$ if and only if
$$\log^2 n > c \log n$$ which will clearly happen as soon as $$\frac{\log^2 n}{\log n}>c$$ i.e., as soon as $\log n>c$.

Note that $\exp(\log^{1+\epsilon} n)$ is superpolynomial for all $\epsilon>0.$

**Edit:** The superpolynomial convergence is essentially what is referred to as *negligibility*.

Comment: Thanks and +1. So a successful predictor should predict with a probability greater than or equal $1-O(ν(n))$, How is the latter evaluated numerically. That's from where should I derive the $O(ν(n))$ numerically? A simple example of a simple algorithm will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is O(v(n)) the error rate? And how is it derived? Practically from the experiment/simulation? Thanks.

Comment: It is implicitly negligibility. Adding this into answer will increase the awareness.

Answer (score 1):

First, that's not the Next Bit Test, which is purely theoretical, but rather an attempt at a practical approximation of it.

From your first citation:

The notation $O(\nu(n))$ is used for any function, $f(n)$, that vanishes faster than the inverse of any polynomial, that is for every polynomial, $poly(n)$, and $n$ large enough, $f (n) < 1/poly (n)$.

So you can think of it as a function that asymptotically approaches 0, very, very quickly. Overall, this means that the probability in question must then be extremely small. Since that probability is |(the chance that an attacker guesses the next bit)-50%| it means the attacker has extremely small advantage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. +1 for explaining the intuition of the notation.

Comment: Just to mention, the paper is a ***second*** attempt of the NBT, and based on improving a previous attempt ***and*** the Shamir's paper (which proves that the NBT proposed by Yao is not universal where Shamir provides a better version of the NBT)